# Make related articles feature with python and django or react

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a blog website backend is Python + Django + DRF. On frontend I have React.

At the article page I want to have "related articles" section and "popular articles". The same I want to have for the root page. For me is so important that these sections will be "user specefic". For example if user have been reading a lot about "France" it would influence to recommended articles and this topic will have more weight than other.

How can I do that?
Can I do that with python?
What technology should I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complex than that. You can show similar topics with whatever front end you have, once you have those topics. I don't know of an out-of-the-box library that returns the similar topics, but there are some pretty complex natural language processing tools that you can use to create some on your own (for example, [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/)).

Answer (score 1):

This Question has nothing to do with Django or Reactjs. What you are looking for are algorithms for recommender systems.